# How do I send an Image rotate request to gprc server with python?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, rpc

I am new to grpc. I am having trouble understanding it. Anyway, I am working based on a protobuf file called: **image.proto**

Below are the contents of my image.proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;

message NLImage {
    bool color = 1;
    bytes data = 2;
    int32 width = 3;
    int32 height = 4;
}


message NLImageRotateRequest {
    enum Rotation {
        NONE = 0;
        NINETY_DEG = 1;
        ONE_EIGHTY_DEG = 2;
        TWO_SEVENTY_DEG = 3;
    }

    Rotation rotation = 1;
    NLImage image = 2;
}

service NLImageService {
    rpc RotateImage(NLImageRotateRequest) returns (NLImage);
    rpc MeanFilter(NLImage) returns (NLImage);
}
```

I was able to create a server.py file, and client.py. I also generated the image_pb2.py from the image.proto file and I generated the image_pb2_grpc.py.

Now, I am stuck into sending an image rotation request from the client to the server, and getting back an appropriate response.

Here is what I have so far tried in my client.py

```
import grpc
# import the generated files
import image_pb2
import image_pb2_grpc

#.......
#.......SEVERAL LINES OF CODE LATER
#.......

print('Input image path is', inputfile)
print('Output path is', outputfile)
print('Mean  is', mean)
print("Rotate is", rotate)
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:5000')
stub = image_pb2_grpc.NLImageServiceStub(channel)


# SEND ROTATION REQUEST IF rotate
img_rotate_request = image_pb2.NLImageRotateRequest()
stub.RotateImage(img_rotate_request, inputfile)
```

I am not sure how to send that RotateImage request properly.

Below is my server.py:

```
import sys, getopt
from google.protobuf.descriptor import EnumDescriptor
import grpc
from concurrent import futures
import time
import numpy as np

# importing grpc generated classes
import image_pb2
import image_pb2_grpc

class NLImageServiceServicer(image_pb2_grpc.NLImageServiceServicer):
   def RotateImage(self, request, context):
      print("Request to rotate image received")
      return image_pb2._NLIMAGE()

   def MeanFilter(self, request, context):
      print("Request to filter received")
      return image_pb2.NLImage()

   server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
   image_pb2_grpc.add_NLImageServiceServicer_to_server(NLImageServiceServicer, server)
   server.add_insecure_port( host + ":" + str(port))
   server.start()
   print("Server started ...on " + host + ":" + port)
   server.wait_for_termination()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eyeballing your code, it appears OK; I've not run it.

You're correctly calling the method: `stub.RotateImage` but you're not correctly creating the message type (`NLImageRotateRequest`) for it. It will be an instance of the class generated for you by `protoc`, probably `image_pb2.NLImageRotateRequest` and this contains `rotation` and `image` properties. The `image` is itself an instance of a class `image_pb2.Image` etc.

Please see this [link](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated) for using protobuf with Python because each language is distinct and Python has some quirks in how you create messages.

At some point, you'll need to read in `inputfile` as bytes in order to populate the `data` property of `image`.

If you've not, perhaps run through the Python [HelloWorld](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/) example on grpc.io. It's basic but it will get you started with gRPC. Then review the link I included above and the protobuf sections on Python.